# How to automatically insert data to database using ajax after several seconds

Tags: php, ajax, database, html, geolocation

I have Geo location code from html5. In this code when I am clicking on the button it will show me the Latitude and Longitude data when I am clicking on "Try It" Button.
Demo: [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)
I have customized the code and inserted the data to database using ajax. Now I want to hie the button, and I want to send the data after 5 seconds automatically.

```
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
  function getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
 }

     function showPosition(position) {
     var lat = position.coords.latitude;
     var long = position.coords.longitude;

     //AJAX CALL THIS WILL PASS THE VALUE OF JAVASCRIPT TO PHP
     $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'ajax-processor.php',
      data: {
        lat: lat,
        long: long
       },
       success: function(html) {
         alert("Success");
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

## To insert my ajax data I have this code, which is directly insert to database  (ajax-processor.php)

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$long = $_POST['long'];

//your code to insert to the database here using the $lat and $long variable
```

Now I want to insert this data after 5 seconds without having any button. In Geo location code I have this code

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
```

I want hide this button, and the latitude, longitude data will be sent to database automatically after 5 seconds. 
In a main word I want to insert my latitude and longitude data will be sent to database after 5 seconds.
Please Help me.

Comment: Try this code: `setTimeout(function() { getLocation();}, 5000);`

Comment: Or shorter `setTimeout(getLocation(), 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change few lines of your code.

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
```

to

```
<button>Try It</button>
```

Then you need to add `jQuery` to set timeout.

```
<script>

setTimeout(function() { 
    getLocation();
}, 5000); // for 5 secs


  function getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
   } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var long = position.coords.longitude;

   //AJAX CALL THIS WILL PASS THE VALUE OF JAVASCRIPT TO PHP
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax-processor.php',
     data: {
       lat: lat,
       long: long
     },
     success: function(html) {
       alert("Success");
     }
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    getLocation();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() { 
 $.ajax({ 
 type:post, 
 url : 'ajax-processor.php', 
 success: function(html) { 
       alert("Success"); 
     } 
   }); 
 }, 500);
```

Comment: 500 - 0.5 second, but 5000 - 5 seconds